# C# & SQL Server - The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, timeout

The question involves SQL Server and C#.

I am trying to execute multiple delete statements in one query. The format has the following structure:

```
DELETE from dbo.table where column = 'value'
```

repeated more than 100000 times

I build the command through a `StringBuilder` and call it that way in my C# code:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However it takes a lot of time to execute and ends with this error:

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server. Executing through Management Studio takes also a lot of time, and let me think that the query isn't performant enough. However, in this case the query is executed successfully.

Obviously, using fewer `DELETE` statements, the query ends properly due it's a very simple query. What is the best way to execute multiple statements and avoid this error?

Comment: Another point to consider: by default, SQL Server uses **row-level locks** and locks only those rows affected by e.g. a `DELETE` statement. However, if you pass 5'000 rows in a single transaction, SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and move the lock to the **entire table** which becomes **exclusively locked** until the transaction finishes. This means: until the transaction finishes, no one can even *read* from that table! So maybe you need to batch up your `DELETE` operations into smaller batches to avoid an exclusive table lock

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do only a single DELETE execution with the "IN" instead of "=" in your query?
Do something like:

```
DELETE from dbo.table where column in ('Param1','Param2','(...)')
```

Also, you could check this article:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20651.sql-server-delete-a-huge-amount-of-data-from-a-table.aspx

Cheers!